# Apache and Ruby on Rails PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, homebrew

I have a custom Apache initializers in order to have my Homebrew binaries accessible:

```
SetEnv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

However, my Rails (3.0.4) applications cannot find any binaries unless full paths are given. For example:

```
begin    
   `convert`
   raise Errno::ENOENT if $?.exitstatus == 127
 rescue Errno::ENOENT
   logger.info "command 'convert' not found: ensure Image Magick is installed"
 end
```

Results in an exception being raised each time (even though the convert binary exists under '/usr/local/bin/convert'). Any ideas on how to fix this so my Rails applications know about the path? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I did a system update or what happened exactly, but I had both Brew and Port configured on my system. I had two initializer files:

```
# ./other/port.conf
SetEnv PATH /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

# ./other/brew.conf
SetEnv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

The soution was to remove the unused `port.conf`. Not sure why this was causing issues in Apache (and I seem to remember it working in the past). However, multiple calls to `SetEnv` seem to overwrite eachother.

Comment: Glad to hear it was something that made sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your specific problem, but it's something to check.

There was a regression in Apache that made `SetEnv` not work for `PATH`. This was fixed in [revision 965679](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=965679) (July, 2010). If you're using an older installation of Apache, you may be hitting this bug.

Comment: I'm on a newer version of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/environments/production.rb`, you can set environment variables like this:

```
ENV["PATH"] = "..."
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really looking for an environment wide setup.